# PostgreSQL 9.5: Permission to deny functions body

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create new role without any grants.

New user can't select on tables, but can see functions body (pl/PgSQL)

I want permissions for new role:

- allow INSERT into one table.
- deny see tables, sequences, functions and function's body.

Is there any way to configure it?

Comment: `ALTER ROLE rolename NOLOGIN;`

Comment: I made small update for permissions, sorry, please check again

Comment: IMO; your question has nothing in programming, it can make more sense in [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) ;).